Remove the ability to boot into safe mode
I have a computer that I am attempting to secure with various programs, however they can be circumvented by booting into Safe Mode and deleting them. Is there any way I could permanently disable safe mode?
I've tried quite a bit but honestly I was expecting someone on stackoverflow to have asked the same question over a decade ago lol
